# How can I find and then replace a substring with PHP regexp?

Tags: php, regex

I have an expression, exactly this:
{gallery id='2'}

I would like to get the id from this expression (in this example the 2) than replace the full tag into another string.

More specifically, I want to do the following:

**String inside the content:**

```
{gallery id='2'}
```

**With preg_replace_callback() I want to call this function:**

```
function changeNumberToGalleryName( $id ){
    //get name of the gallery from database where ID = $id
    ....
    ....
    return $galleryname;
}
```

I want to replace the **{gallery id='2'}** with the **name of gallery**.

Thanks for advice!

Comment: Well, you need an expression obviously; have you tried writing one?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace("/{\s?\w+\s?id\s?=\s?'\d+'\s?}/", $gallername, $text);
```

Comment: A couple of minor comments: you don't need [] around the \w and the \d if they're the only eligible character classes, and you might want to allow 0 or more whitespace ( \s* ) between the various tokens. Something like `{\s*\w+\s+id\s*=\s*'\s*\d+\s*'\s*}` would probably be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify your function you can do it like this:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~{gallery id=\'\K\d+~',
                             function ($match) {
                                 return changeNumberToGalleryName($match[0]);
                             },
                             $str);
```

But if you can modify it (i.e. replace all occurence of `$id` by `$id[0]` in his body), you can write:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~{gallery id=\'\K\d+~',
                             'ChangeNumberToGalleryName',
                             $str);
```

But do you need really a function to do that? If the gallery names are into an associative (or indexed) array, example:

```
array(
"1" => "gallery 1 name"
"2" => "gallery 2 etc.
)

or

array('nop', 'gallery 1 name', 'gallery 2 name' ...)
```

you only have to use the anonymous function:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~{gallery id=\'\K\d+~',
                             function ($match) { return myarray[$match[0]]; },
                             $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Matching the full tag and capturing the identifier:

```
$re = "/{gallery id='([^']+)'}/";
preg_replace_callback($re, function($match) {
    return changeNumberToGalleryName($match[1]);
}, $string);
```

The expression `([^']+)` matches anything until an apostrophe is found and captures the found string into the first memory location of the match; I later use `$match[1]` to pass the value along.

I'm using a callback here to extract the identifier via the memory capture and then passing that to your function; that way you don't have to modify your function.